# check json and notifications with closed app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I don't know where to start or which way to go, I've been looking at Alarm Manager, WorkManager, Services.

I wanted to use PeriodicWorkRequest (starting with something simple, showing a toast) but this has a minimum span of 15 minutes which does not work for me if I need to consult the Json every minute and I would even like to consult it every second.

I want to implement a section in my application so that the user receives notifications.
The user will select a value which can decide if he wants to be notified when the value has been exceeded or the value is below.
The value will be comparing with a value obtained through a Json with Http Request, if possible comparing every minute.

How can I achieve this? It is worth mentioning that this should continue to run even when the user closes the app or restarts the device.

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT recommended to perform network operations frequently as it will drain the user’s battery. What you probably need is to have a Socket connection if your value changes rapidly and it has to be updated in realtime.

However, having an IntentService that runs on the background is what you’re probably looking for.

Comment: First of all thanks for the recommendation,
In several posts I have read the issue of the battery and of course I understand it, but as you mentioned, the value that I would be consulting changes many times in a minute and this value may exceed the value set by the user and you will not be notified.
For now I'm going to read about IntentService as recommended, hoping for some other answer that may help me, but anticipating a bit, would this work even if the application is closed and the device restarts?

Comment: If your value changes frequently, it's best to have a Socket connection rather than HTTP requests. You can make IntentService work on device boot up of course. This is what WhatsApp is using for retrieving realtime messages.